# How to get the list of remotely modified files in CVS

Tags: cvs

I'd like to have the list of remotely modified files in CVS.
I am using WINCVS and I cannot see any options to get the modified files
on CVS .

Answer (score 1):

I think the command you are looking for is called `cvs status`

If you have a bash or similar shell, you can get a list of
remotely modified files like this:

```
E:\tmp> cvs status | grep "Need"
cvs status: Examining .
File: A.h               Status: Needs Patch
File: B.h               Status: Needs Patch
File: B.cpp             Status: Needs Patch
```

If you really want to get the files (instead of just seeing the list),
use `cvs update`.